# Woocommerce Multiple domain mapping

Tags: woocommerce, dns

For a Woocommerce webshop I'm looking to use differtent domainnames on the same webshop installation. I know this is possible with Wordpress, but is it also working for Woocommerce?

So:
domain1.com is the webshop installation
domain2.com goes to domain1.com but keeps the domainname in the url domain2.com/product/... etc.

What do I need to do to make this work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Configure a HTTP redirect from domain2.com to domain1.com. Browser then looks for new URL location and automatically deals with it.

Comment: But will it show the url of domain2.com in the browser?

Comment: Yes it shows, this is not a rare site. Suppose if we type google.com in browser, and when the final page loads you can see  https:// www. google. com (gave spaces so that stackoverflow wont parse it to url) something like that, what is happening under the hood is HTTP redirection (3xx)